# Questions about Borel-Weil-Bott theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm trying to understand the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem and its proof, but I am confused about some points.

First, does the theorem have both complex geometric and algebro geometric versions? Some literatures state the theorem for complex semisimple Lie groups and consider holomorphic sections while others state for semisimple, simply-connected, complex algebraic groups. The line bundle $\mathcal{L}(\lambda)$ also seem to be considered in different settings depending on literature. Or do we not necessarily have to distinguish between them?

Second, in [S. Kumar's note on Borel-Weil-Bott](https://kumar.math.unc.edu/notes/kumar_notes_03.pdf) the author says that the theorem also holds for any connected reductive group. What is the precise statement of that, or where can I find the statement? I guess that the same construction of $\mathcal{L}(\lambda)$ can be used and the statement of the theorem will be the same, but I'm not sure. For example, I'm not very sure if the characters of $B$ and $T$ would be still in one-to-one correspondence.
(If the answer to my first question is that the theorem has two different versions, then I would be more interested in the algebro-geometric one.)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this is super helpful, but I learned about the topic from the (superb) notes by Jacob Keller http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2018/REUPapers/Keller.pdf which contain a few nice explicit examples.
From my understanding, the setup in these papers is entirely in the complex algebraic groups setting.